# How to make a 3D text in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Using Qt Creator 4.9.1 (based on Qt 5.12.3), I'm trying to make a simple text in 3D like "Hello 3D" by a QML project.

I've searched much but unfortunately have not found a simple example for this purpose. Docs suck in this case too.

This is the code I use for that text:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import Qt3D.Extras 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

ExtrudedTextMesh {
        depth: 2.5
        font.family: "Helvetica"
        text: "Hello 3D" 
    }
}
```

The issue is that no text is shown on the application's window!
Is there a way to fix this please?

Comment: You can't just put it into window, you need Entity, Material and whatever else. See more info [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-overview.html)

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the page. It includes many other stuff which are all new for me. The projects there are also just confusing because they contain several files while my project is only few lines. How would you modify the code above to put the text "Hello 3D" on the window, please? (the simplest way)

Comment: You cannot do it in several lines of code. 3D is a pretty complicated thing. A minimum you need: camera, light, entity with your mesh, material, shaders. Get some simple example from QtCreator set and try to modify it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to use a `Texture` with `sourceItem` set. This will allow you to use any 2D rendering you wish such as `Rectangle` with a centered `Text`:

```
Texture {
    sourceItem: Rectangle {
        width: 150
        height: 150
        color: Qt.rgba(0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.75)
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Hello 3D"
            color: "white"
            font.pointSize: 12
        }
    }
}
```

In the following example, I render the above `Texture` onto a spinning 3D cube:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick3D

Page {
    anchors.fill: parent
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    Node {
        id: standAloneScene
        DirectionalLight { ambientColor: Qt.rgba(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) }
        Node {
            id: node
            Model {
                id: model
                source: "#Cube"
                materials: [
                    DefaultMaterial {
                        diffuseMap: Texture {
                            sourceItem: Rectangle {
                               width: 150
                               height: 150
                               color: Qt.rgba(0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.75)
                               Text {
                                   anchors.centerIn: parent
                                   text: "Hello 3D"
                                   color: "white"
                                   font.pointSize: 12
                               }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
        OrthographicCamera {
            id: cameraOrthographicFront
            y: 800; z: 1000
            Component.onCompleted: lookAt(node)
        }
    }
    View3D {
        anchors.fill: parent
        importScene: standAloneScene
        camera: cameraOrthographicFront
    }
    NumberAnimation {
        target: model
        property: "eulerRotation.y"
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        running: true
        from: 720; to: 0
        duration: 10000
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)